# how can i sort elements on drop using JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have few `'li'` elements. I can drag and drop elements...but,my requirement is i need to sort element after drop(element has to move to destination after mouse release). Please help me...
Here is the code i'm using,

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    revert: true,
    start : function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
$( "li selector" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    start : function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there not a `onDrop` event, or something similar you can listen for, to then run your sorting function?

If not, you could run a function that binds to the jQuery event `.mouseup()`, which then fires your sorting function.

https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

Comment: I need to stop 'li' moving effect when drag is sarted....I need to show a squared dotted line box as it is moving instead of 'li' element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RmLAA/

In this link, 'Element1' is moving along with the cursor,but i need to show a dotted square box instead of 'Element1' and it has to sort after mouse release.